# Suppress `The query uses a row limiting operator ('Skip'/'Take') without an 'OrderBy' operator` warning

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following C# code using Entity Framework

```cs
var numberToSkip = _random.Next(maxNumber);
await query.Skip(numberToSkip).FirstAsync();
```

This code gives a fair warning:

> The query uses a row limiting operator ('Skip'/'Take') without an 'OrderBy' operator. This may lead to unpredictable results. If the 'Distinct' operator is used after 'OrderBy', then make sure to use the 'OrderBy' operator after 'Distinct' as the ordering would otherwise get erased.

Usually, it is absolutely fine to show that, and I have to use `OrderBy(x => x.Id)` here.
However, in this particular case, I want just a random row and don't want to make an ordering, even if it does not affect the performance.

How can I suppress this warning here? I don't want to suppress it for the ho

Comment: Maybe it would help if you show how the ```query``` is created and what's inside before you call ```.Skip``` on it

Answer (score 3):

If you want a random value then it *is* important that you order the items, and it's critical that you not suppress the warning.

Not ordering doesn't mean the results are in a *random* order, it means they're in an *arbitrary* order.  Arbitrary is not random.  It means that the implementation is free to use whatever order it wants, i.e. your query could return the same value every single time, even though you're skipping by a random number.

So since your requirements are an evenly distributed random value, you either need to actually order by something (anything that will be consistent).

If you actually *want* any arbitrary value, and really don't need a random value, then there's no need to have the skipped random value, so the way to remove the warning is to remove the skip, since you don't actually need a properly randomized value.